# angular and linear velocity of an object let go of while spinning

Tags: angular-velocity

Can someone explain to me what exactly happens when let’s say you are holding an object like a 1 ft x 6 ft piece of wood.  When you are spinning every part of the wood is spinning at a different linear velocity , so when you let go of it what will be the linear velocity of the center of mass as well as what will be the angular velocity the wood will be spinning around the center of mass.  For this question let’s assume my hands are 2 feet from center of rotation the wood is 6 ft long and I’m rotatong at 30 rotations per minute .

Answer (score 1):

Both quantities of (linear) momentum and angular momentum are conserved, so you only need to figure out what is the linear and angular velocities of the wood while it is spinning.
You will; however, also need to know the mass distribution, thickness and orientation of the plank.